# How to get the answer string from a socket.write('parameter') node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

In a nodejs application, I open a connection

```
var net = require('net');
dataServer = net.createConnection(port, host);
```

... need to send some parameters

```
dataServer.write("paramA"); 
dataServer.write("paramB"); 
dataServer.write("paramC"); 
dataServer.write("paramD");
```

... All right here ... 
Here is the question... How to get the server's answer (A,B,C,D) regarding the parameters that were passed? knowing they will be made ​​several requests that can be answered at different times .. there is another way?

Comment: Send a timestamp with it, and have the server echo the specific one back with its response. Then match it up

Comment: You listen with event `data` like `dataServer.on('data',function(){})`. See http://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_event_data